# Правильно ли выражение "занять позу"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Можно ли сказать "занять позу", или верный вариант только "принять позу"?

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве случаев используется выражение ***принять позу,*** а сочетание ***занять позу*** встречается, но редко.

Если рассмотреть эти случаи, то там скорее речь идет не только позе, но и **о месте, на котором надо эту позу занять**, например:

― Он **занял позу** перед телекамерами, над которыми враз загорелись белые лампы. [Александр Проханов. Господин Гексоген (2001)]

Здесь я уже **занял позу** для катапультирования, сижу, жду. [Анатолий Докучаев, 2003.04.15]

А в этом предложении речь, вероятно, идет **о ролевой вакансии**:

А это не только деформировало в глазах общественности на Западе роль нравственных критериев в политике, но и не позволяло ему **занять позу моралиста,** как это бывало в других случаях. [Георгий Арбатов. Человек Системы (2002)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (для дискуссии)

Можно, конечно, сказать, что это **неразборчивые авторы**.
Но сочетания ***принять пузу*** и ***занять место*** сюда не   очень подходят по тому смыслу, который вложил в них автор. **Значит, нужно переделывать предложения, а как?** Усложнять описание всех действий не хотелось бы.

Comment: В докладе Гагарина речь не идёт о месте: "здесь" означает _момент времени_, когда закончились вибрации в конструкции ("потом этот зуд проходит" - в предыдущем предложении это элемент хронологии событий). Занять какое-либо другое место у космонавта не было возможности. Он сначала поставил ноги на кресло (изменил позу там, где находился), дождался прекращения вибраций и принял позу, нужную для катапультирования. Конечно же, в разговорном жанре доклада сказанное допустимо, чего нельзя сказать о "занятии позы моралиста" (правильнее было "встать в позу" - речь не идёт о позе скульптуры Родена).

Comment: Перед телекамерами ничто не мешает просто "расположиться", "усесться" (по стилю это сочетается с "враз") или "занять место"; если нужно - "в позе такой-то, того-то", "приняться позировать".

Comment: Alex_ander, Вы говорите о значениях слов, но не приводите примеров с заменой. Тогда было бы наглядно видно, подходит ли другое слово, соответствует ли оно стилю. Может быть, смысл не тот или он книжное, не для этого  текста.

Answer (score 1):

Изредка встречаются случаи авторской неразборчивости, однако "**занять**" можно только место в пространстве, лишив этого места других. **Позу** же, по определению (*Положение, принимаемое человеческим телом*, Ушаков https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/952270), **принимают**; в предложном сочетании - в позу *становятся*.